# How to continue Gradle execution if one of the dependsOn tasks failed

Tags: gradle, task, build.gradle, gradlew, build-tools

I want to have this `task allTests(dependsOn: ['runOnChrome', 'runOnFirefox']) {}` and in case of one of the failed tasks i want to continue execution, similar as i would run `./gradlew runOnChrome runOnFirefox --continue`

If i run `./gradlew allTests --continue` it stops when one of the task failed

Comment: I don't find this to be the case on gradle `5.6`. When I tested it, both tasks ran and failed even though both threw exceptions. Without the `--continue` flag, only the first one ran